# Linux cannot detect 2560x1440 144z capability of Vega 64

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics, xrandr, monitors

Using KDE Neon, a Vega 64, and a Pixio px277h, I have tried to manually make xrandr use the setting for 144hz because it does not seem to detect this properly. The monitor has 144hz capability, the cable that comes with it also probably does (it is labeled high speed), and the Vega 64 has HDMI 2.0, so there should be no problem on the hardware side. Here is some more information:

```
uname -r
4.15.0-39-generic

cvt 2560 1440 144
"2560x1440_144.00"  808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync
```

xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_144.00"  808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 2560x1440_144.00
```

xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 2560x1440_144.00

```
xrandr: unrecognized option '2560x1440_144.00'
```

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     59.95  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.95  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440_144.00 143.91
```

Snippets from Xorg.0.log pertaining to EDID:

```
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-2
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer: OPD  Model: 2700  Serial#: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Year: 2018  Week: 22
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID Version: 1.3
    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Digital Display Input
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 60  vert.: 34
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:2:2
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Default color space is primary color space
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported established timings:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@72Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@56Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@72Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported standard timings:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #3: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #4: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #5: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): #6: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 241.5 MHz   Image Size:  597 x 336 mm
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 302.1 MHz   Image Size:  597 x 336 mm
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Stereo: left channel on sync
[    16.812] side-by-side interleaved(II) AMDGPU(0): Ranges: V min: 40 V max: 101 Hz, H min: 25 H max: 110 kHz, PixClock max 315 MHz
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Monitor name: PX227H-HDMI2
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  510 x 287 mm
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  510 x 287 mm
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 540  v_sync: 542  v_sync_end 547 v_blanking: 562 v_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  510 x 287 mm
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1390  h_sync_end 1430 h_blank_end 1650 h_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 720  v_sync: 725  v_sync_end 730 v_blanking: 750 v_border: 0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID (in hex):
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    00ffffffffffff003e04002700000000
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    161c0103803c2278feee95a3544c9926
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    0f5054afcf00714f81c081809500a9c0
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    b300d1c00101565e00a0a0a029503020
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    350055502100001a037600a0a0a02950
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    30203500555021000030000000fd0028
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    65196e1f000a202020202020000000fc
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    005058323237482d48444d4932000155
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    020339f14f0102030405079012131416
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    1f5f5d6923090707830100006d030c00
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    10003844200060030200e305ff01e30f
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    0000e6060701605346023a801871382d
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    40582c4500fe1f1100001e011d801871
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    1c1620582c2500fe1f1100009e011d00
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    7251d01e206e285500fe1f1100001e00
[    16.812] (II) AMDGPU(0):    00000000000000000000000000000024
[    16.812] (--) AMDGPU(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 340000KHz
...
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "OPD", prod id 9984
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring: We don't handle stereo.
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz eP)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x480i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1478 1602 1716  480 488 494 525 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.7 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x576i"x0.0   27.00  1440 1464 1590 1728  576 580 586 625 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.6 kHz e)
[    21.506] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
```

The option with information from cvt and input with addmode are there, but why can't I use it? How can I fix this? I know that a Vega graphics card has the capability to do 2560x1440 and 144hz based on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB5RRdTi9bY

Comment: Also have a look at `Xorg.0.log`, the EDID, and the result of the modeline checks. Even if your monitor supports 144 Hz, your **graphics card** may have a limit on the pixel clock rate, and may be unable to do 144 Hz at 2560x1440 (though it may do 144 Hz at lower resolutions).

Comment: More specifically, you seem to be using `--addmode` incorrectly (without a prior `--newmode`), hence the link to the "duplicate" question, which gives a more detailed example usage.

Comment: Here is a video of someone reviewing the monitor. He is using a Vega graphics card and achieving 144hz.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB5RRdTi9bY

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the first xrandr command:

```
 xrandr --newmode 2560x1440_144.00  "808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync"
```

And a wrong last line:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 2560x1440_144.00
```

Comment: I did use --newmode first, but hadn't put it in the commands. The option for --newmode where the quotes are not around the name, but the parameters seems to not work.

xrandr --newmode 2560x1440_144.00  "808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync"
xrandr: failed to parse '2560x1440_144.00' as a mode specification
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.